# Regex for complex password validation

Tags: c#, regex, passwords

I looked around on stackoverflow, etc, but haven't found a good answer for this..Does regex support writing a rule like this? If so is there any regex experts our there who can help me write this, I am a big newb to regex and in a time crunch...

I know I can do this with a manual function in c# using c# char, number methods, but I would like to use regex if I can for this..

Requirement :

- At least 8 characters long

  - 2 letters
  - 2 digits
  - 1 Upper case
  - 1 Lower case
  - 1 Symbol

Comment: If these are the actual rules you're going to use, I hate you. :)

Comment: I didn't make up these rules :)

Comment: Exactly 8 chars or at least 8 chars?

Comment: I think it should have a Greek letter too..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Don't forget a hieroglyph.

Comment: Regex would be way too much complex.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^(?=(.*\d){2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d]).{8,}$
    ---------  --------------------- --------------- -----
        |               |                    |          |->match 8 or more characters
        |               |                    |->match further only if theres anything except letter or digit
        |               |->match further only if there is an upper-lower case letter
        |
        |->match further only if there are two digits anywhere
```

[Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/J56eAXqyK0)

Comment: @Anirudh - Ah after the edit, it works now..  I wouldn't use it but `+1` for hacking that together.

Comment: +1, Never know there is such thing as `(?=` in regular expression. Great work.

Comment: I will test this a while and mark this as answer if it passed my validation tests. Thanks.

Comment: @kyleb - One drawback with this is you can't tell the user *why* their password is invalid, you can only tell them it isn't.

Comment: That is true I can't tell them what is wrong, but that is not a requirement right now. If it does become one I will revert to using C# instead.

Comment: I also have one more regex password validator I need to write for different people on my site. I tried using yours and modifying it and I almost have it....The rule is a password that is 1. Always 5 chars long, 2. 3 or 4 letter word, 3. 1 or 2 digits. The problem is my regex I wrote allows you to put in "fox$5". Here is my regex ^(?=(.*\d){1,2})(?=([a-z]){3,4}).{5}$

Comment: @kyleb you were close..this is what you are looking for `^(?=(.*\d){1,2})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3,4})[a-zA-Z\d]{5}$`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it also needs to be all lowercase

Comment: @kyleb you can remove `A-Z`

Comment: @kyleb Those are horrible password rules! I'd never create an account on such a site, out of principle. Or if I did, I'd promptly forget my password! I uses a random password generator, and it *still* doesn't always have >= 2 numbers.

Comment: @kyleb as jpaugh pointed out with that password criteria,anyone can break the password within a minute..

Comment: I never said it was good criteria. I just do the job as they tell me. I tried fighting it some but they wouldn't budge.

Comment: Got it! ^(?=(.*\d){1,2})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3,4})[a-z\d]{5}$

Comment: I have 3 different password policies on my site. I have the first 2 working. But the last one I thought I had working but it isn't. The password policy is a. Exactly 6 characters b. At least 2 letters c. At least 2 digits d. all lowercase. Here is my example I can't make work http://www.rubular.com/r/FJlmyDFbCH

Comment: I fixed it, was missing a star.. ^(?=(.*\d){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,}).{6}$

Comment: Oh and this isn't as hackable as I originally wrote the question lol. It was suppose to say : At least:
   - 8 characters long
   - 2 letters
   - 2 digits
   - 1 Upper case
   - 1 Lower case
   - 1 Symbol

Answer (score 18):

You are much better off writing a simple validation routine for a password that has all of these checks.

A regular expression doesn't seem as the best (or most extensible) solution for this particular problem.

```
if(password.Length < 8)
  return false;

var letters = 0;
var digits = 0;
var uppers = 0;
var lowers = 0;
var symbols = 0;
foreach(var ch in password)
{
   if (char.IsLetter(ch)) letters++;
   if (char.IsDigit(ch)) digits++;
   ....
} 

if(letters < 2) return false;
...
```

Comment: While a regex would work, this is significantly more maintainable solution.

Comment: I am leaning towards this but I want to see if anyone can create a regular expression like this first..

Comment: +1, nice, conceivable and more maintainable, as to be compared to long-long regular expressions.

Comment: @kyleb, I am attempting too, but from what I have picture, it is way too long.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend going the way Oded's answer did, but I think LINQ is a more readable and explicit validation mechanism in this case.

```
string p = "psW%Rd32";
return p.Length >= 8 &&
    p.Count(c => char.IsDigit(c)) >= 2 &&
    p.Count(c => char.IsUpper(c)) >= 1 &&
    p.Count(c => char.IsLower(c)) >= 1) ...
```

Comment: Though I like it, you _are_ iterating multiple times over the string (once per `Count`).

Comment: return p.Length == 8 is wrong. you must have AT LEAST 8 characters

Comment: `+1` - Though it would require many iterations through the string, it's easy to read and well organized.

Comment: I knew you'd pick on performance. :) I assumed this is for realtime validation of a textbox, not iterating over thousands of passwords after the fact. In this case we're iterating realistically no more than 1-2 dozen characters, any performance benefits will not be felt on any CPU from the last 15 years.

Comment: @Damith Depends what the OP wants to enforce, it's just an example.

Comment: Great! Liked this one. Though I will have to add that your method is imperative rather than declarative (as in the regex). Ergo, there will be a small impact on performance.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this method.

```
 private bool ValidatePassword(string password, out string ErrorMessage)
{
    var input = password;
    ErrorMessage = string.Empty;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        throw new Exception("Password should not be empty");
    }

    var hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
    var hasUpperChar = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+");
    var hasMiniMaxChars = new Regex(@".{8,8}");
    var hasLowerChar = new Regex(@"[a-z]+");
    var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");

    if (!hasLowerChar.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one lower case letter";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!hasUpperChar.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one upper case letter";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!hasMiniMaxChars.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should not be less than or greater than 8 characters";
        return false;
    }
    else if (!hasNumber.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one numeric value";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!hasSymbols.IsMatch(input))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Password should contain At least one special case characters";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 : this fails Accessibility Standards - all error messages should be returned in a single response. This method could cause multiple attempts of the same input with differing error responses. It should be refactored to test all rules and return a collection of errors